# Automated custom software installation using bash script in Linux

Tags: linux, bash, ubuntu

I use Ubuntu 14.04 LTS in my laptop. I have my own customized Ubuntu, where most of the packages are already installed. 
We made this customized Ubuntu before we install Jupiter. It misses Jupiter package there. With Ubuntu 14.04,
 my laptop overheats always. For this, everytime I do new installation of Jupiter power management tool. 
I have to add ppa in sources.list then do install. I would like to automate this process.Please help me out here.

Comment: Which version of ubuntu 14.04 do you use?

Comment: 3rd, I already have so many packages installed there.So, I don't want to install fresh install of new system and install all softwares.

Comment: You can try latest Ubuntu LTE versions 14.04 5th or 16.04. I believe they have enhanced so many features there.

Comment: StackOverflow is about helping people fix their programming code. Requests for tutorials, research, tools, recommendations, libraries, and code are off-topic.  ***Please*** read  http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask , http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask ,  http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve  and take the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) before posting more Qs here. Good luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can run this bash script file. You have to run this script as root user.

**/* you have to change xenial to trusty. or you can go and open the folder /etc/apt/sources.d.list/. Open file jolicloud-team-ubuntu.. something (note: it is based on your OS version and provide the value for variable CHECK as I gave to my xenial (16.04) system */**

**/* OUTCHECK variable represents the path /etc/apt/sources.list.d/jolicloud-team-ubuntu-ppa-xenial.list, where there is source reference. And "deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/jolicloud-team/ppa/ubuntu xenial main" is the content inside jolicloud-team-ubuntu-ppa-xenial.list file */**

I can't install jupiter because it is discontinued. In this link https://askubuntu.com/questions/285434/is-there-a-power-saving-application-similar-to-jupiter, they said, there is better alternative TLP.

## Probably it still works for your 14.04.

Now, your full script looks something like this.

```
 # -y for auto ENTER press by own
export CHECK="deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/jolicloud-team/ppa/ubuntu xenial main" 
export OUTCHECK="$(grep "$CHECK" "/etc/apt/sources.list.d/jolicloud-team-ubuntu-ppa-xenial.list")" 
if [ "$OUTCHECK" ]
then
    echo "repository source is already added"
else
        #if /etc/apt/sources.list doen not contains repository of jupiter then add this
        add-apt-repository ppa:jolicloud-team/ppa -y
        export OUT=$?
        while [ $OUT != 0 ]
            do 
                apt-get update
        done
fi

if ! dpkg -l | grep -qw "jupiter*" # -l for listing, -qw for  matching whole words in quite/silent mode 
    then
        #install using this line of code
#I can't install jupiter because it is discontinued for my OS.
#Probably it still works for your 14.04.
        apt-get install jupiter
else 
    echo "Jupiter is already installed in your system"
fi
```